# При вводе символьного массива на языке СИ происходит нечто странное

Tags: c, массивы, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
 
 
int main()
{
    const int N = 5;
    char mas[N];
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)        //Заполнение массива c клавиатуры
    {
        printf("mas[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%c", &mas[i]);
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)             // Вывод массива на экран
        printf("%c", mas[i]);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что тут не так?

Comment: По скриншоту не очень понятно, что именно произошло в ходе ввода, опишите подробнее

Comment: У вас в первый и четвертый элементы пишется перевод строки `\n`. В принципе, можете сделать так: `scanf("\n%c", &mas[i]);`.

Comment: Перед `scanf` надо ещё добавить `fflush(stdout);` чтобы printf вывел на экран надпись.

Comment: При команде `scanf` это происходит автоматически. Так что не надо.  @zed

Comment: @AlexGlebe это *может* происходить, но не гарантируется: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123528

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После `scanf` буквы остаётся в буфере конец строки. Этот буфер надо очистить.

```
scanf("%c", &mas[i]);
while(getc(stdin)!='\n');
```